How do I solve the booting issue with qemu vexpress-a9 zImage?
I'm studying about the boot loader.
I aim to build the Linux kernel and boot the zImage on qemu-system-arm. First, I installed a cross-compiler for vexpress-a9. Using crosstool-ng, I installed arm-cortexa9_neon-linux-gnueabihf, but I changed the target vendor name from cortexa9_neon to hello. After building, the following executable files were created in x-tools/bin.
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-addr2line     arm-linux-addr2line
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-ar            arm-linux-ar
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-as            arm-linux-as
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-c++           arm-linux-c++
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-c++filt       arm-linux-c++filt
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-cc            arm-linux-cc
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-cpp           arm-linux-cpp
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-ct-ng.config  arm-linux-ct-ng.config
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-dwp           arm-linux-dwp
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-elfedit       arm-linux-elfedit
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-g++           arm-linux-g++
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-gcc           arm-linux-gcc
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-gcc-13.2.0    arm-linux-gcc-13.2.0
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-gcc-ar        arm-linux-gcc-ar
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-gcc-nm        arm-linux-gcc-nm
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-gcc-ranlib    arm-linux-gcc-ranlib
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-gcov          arm-linux-gcov
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-gcov-dump     arm-linux-gcov-dump
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-gcov-tool     arm-linux-gcov-tool
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-gprof         arm-linux-gprof
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-ld            arm-linux-ld
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-ld.bfd        arm-linux-ld.bfd
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-ld.gold       arm-linux-ld.gold
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-ldd           arm-linux-ldd
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-lto-dump      arm-linux-lto-dump
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-nm            arm-linux-nm
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-objcopy       arm-linux-objcopy
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-objdump       arm-linux-objdump
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-populate      arm-linux-populate
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-ranlib        arm-linux-ranlib
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-readelf       arm-linux-readelf
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-size          arm-linux-size
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-strings       arm-linux-strings
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-strip         arm-linux-strip

Next, I downloaded Linux version 6.6.33 and built it using the following commands.
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-


I then attempted to boot using the zImage with the following qemu command. However, the outcome was as follows.
qemu-system-arm -M vexpress-a9 -m 128M -kernel zImage -nographic -append "console=ttyAMA0 root=/dev/mmcblk0 ro"


There is no progress at all. I expected the kernel to load and potentially produce a panic log, but nothing is being outputted.
Thanks for your helps!...
ps. I tried another command to build the kernel.
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-hello-linux-


But there is no output log too.
